# Publish a website built from sphinx docs in Github Pages problem

Tags: python-sphinx, github-pages

I am using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) to build a website for documentation. I want to use [Github User Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) to publish my website but got some problems.

When I use domain .github.io to access my website, browser cannot load full site. It just loads html file and fail in load .js. Here is warning error in browser.

Loading failed for the  with source “https://.github.io/_static/js/modernizr.min.js”. .github.io:33:1

[Here](https://github.com/vutang/vutang.github.io) is my website reporsitory.

Does anyone know what happens? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://.github.io/_static/js/modernizr.min.js is not a valid URL. Did you read the documentation for how to set up a custom hostname for GitHub User Pages?

Comment: Sorry barry hunter, may be this is mistake when typing. The valid URL is vutang.github.io.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about how you publish your site. Only you can reproduce the issue with your repo. The GitHub Pages guide is your best bet for learning how to publish built Sphinx pages, then whatever tutorials you find through a standard web search.

Comment: Hi Steve, 
I found that my browser can not load file with "_static" in link “https://.github.io/_static/js/modernizr.min.js”.

If I change "_static" to "static", browser can load file normally. But by now I don't know how to change "_static" to "static" in Sphinx.

Comment: (1) https://vutang.github.io/static/js/modernizr.min.js is a 404. Please provide a valid URL to your file. (2) Configure where static files go in your `conf.py` with [`html_static_path`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_static_path).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Steve,

1. Here is my website repository in github: 
https://github.com/vutang/vutang.github.io, I think this URL is not wrong. 

2. My project directory after changing html_static_path: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5wa42FlZW2CQa150G28j4SxMg9oD3zu/view?usp=sharing 

As you can see the html result in ./vux_build/html/_static/. When I read index.html in my local machine, browser can load whole page but it went wrong with github page.

Comment: Your docs get published at https://vutang.github.io/ without any problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you, Steve. I can not fix this error in Sphinx, so I changed to use Mkdocs for my site.

Comment: @VuTang, see https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/  (You solved the problem a different way. I'm putting that link here for anyone else who runs into this problem in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

you can add `.nojekyll` to the root of repo to bypass the rule.

---

*I put it here because I almost missed the folded comment above:*

> @VuTang, see github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages (You solved the problem a different way. I'm putting that link here for anyone else who runs into this problem in the future.)